# Embed custom form twice, one instance open and another is close with React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

How should i keep custom form twice, one instance open and another is close on the same page that is built with React js?
I have created one react app that is having form functionality and added it to our web page. Now I want an another instance of this app to have same functionality but as a open form in my page. How could I achieve this?  Any Suggestion or link would be helpful regarding having multiple instance of a same react app form, if provided.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky but can be done.

**GenericForm.js** (your generic form component)

```
const Form = (props: Props) => { ... }

const createReduxForm = reduxForm({ validate }) // validate is optional - just to show you can pass other stuff as usual

const ReduxForm = createReduxForm(Form)

export default ReduxForm
```

The takeaway from above is that you're declaring a `Form` without a form name.

View where the generic form gets used:

```
import GenericForm from '../GenericForm' // adjust for your paths

const View = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <GenericForm onSubmit={...} form="Form1" />
      <GenericForm onSubmit={...} form="Form2" />
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

This exploits the fact that redux-from uses the form name to connect/update to the store. The `form` prop is the key to the redux store. So by passing form name dynamically, you can reuse the same generic form in a single view.

So that's the hard part. The easy part is keeping one open and one closed - you can use an accordion control or just some custom logic to show hide forms on the page for that.

Comment: Thanks @Mrchief for your valuable answer, I don't know how much you get to understand my question but I was able to get some sensethrough your answer of custom approach for my application. I call ReactDOM.render twice to generate two instance of my application with same store and functionality,